# Access to WSDL file deployed in IIS Manager from a client distant machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, .net-framework-version, iis-manager

I have an application(virtual folder defining as an application)in IIS Manager from Windows Server 2012 R2. I want to have access to my application from a client distant machine.
when i type this URL  http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/App/Convert.asmx?WSDL for example on the server's browser it's working. But when i try it with my local machine. it's not working.

I ping the server's IP address from my machine in the cmd and the ping is successful.

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a server or network admin who can help you, or are you the serveradmin? I'd first look at the Windows firewall and/or firewalls between you and the server

Comment: If you can try to browse to the default website with http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/ then that would tell you whether the problem is your application or the network/firewall/connection. Pinging does not prove you don't have a firewall issue because the firewall will be specific to portnumbers

Comment: I am not a serveradmin but i have access to the server with an admin Account from a Remote Desktop. When i browse the default website with xx.xxx.xxx.xx with my brower's client machine that give me "This site is inaccessible" . 
For the firwall, i will making sure when i 'm in the company.

Comment: The firewall is disabled. On the other hand, when I ping from the server to the client machine (my machine), the ping does not succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725458/get-value-submitted-with-post-method-web-service/41736255#41736255) just follow carefully.

It begins from creating a Webservice to Deployment and Calling it to another project.

Good Luck!